# What's wrong with this simple C code?

Tags: c, memory-leaks, error-handling

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int m,n; scanf("%d %d",&m,&n);
    char ar[m][n];
    char buf[n];
    int a,b;
    for(a=0;a<m;a++)
    {
        gets(buf);
        for(b=0;b<n;b++) ar[a][b] = buf[b];
    }
    for(a=0;a<m;a++,printf("\n")) for(b=0;b<n;b++) printf("%c",ar[a][b]);
    return 0;
}
```

This code takes **m** lines as input from `stdin`, each line containing **n** characters, and prints all the lines to `stdout`. Simple as that. But there seems to be a memory leak, because the first time `gets(buf)` is encountered, its execution is skipped.

I tried it in C++ too, thinking the memory leak will disappear. Here is the code:

```
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int m,n; scanf("%d %d",&m,&n);
    char **ar = new char*[m];
    char *buf = new char[n];
    int a,b;
    for(a=0;a<m;a++)
    {
        gets(buf);
        ar[a] = new char[n];
        for(b=0;b<n;b++) ar[a][b] = buf[b];
    }
    for(a=0;a<m;a++,printf("\n")) for(b=0;b<n;b++) printf("%c",ar[a][b]);
    return 0;
}
```

But it is behaving exactly the same.

Here is some sample input and output:

```
2 3
abc
def
```

output:

```
x��
abc
```

GDB doesn't seem to show anything up too. Please help..

Comment: You should use braces on your for loops. Without them your code is very difficult to read.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not a "memory leak". The problem is that the first `gets()` call reads the newline from when you enter the two dimensions on the first line; it puts zero characters into the buffer, but you print 5, which is why you get a line of garbage.

Add a "\n" at the end of the `scanf()` format string so `scanf()` consumes the newline, and your program will work perfectly. Note that `gets()` is terribly unsafe; using `fgets(buf, n, stdin)` is much preferred.

Comment: That worked! and also I'd like to ask..what makes gets() unsafe?

Comment: If gets() is not thread safe then its okay. Since my program is gonna be single threaded only.

Comment: It's not to do with threads. The problem is that there's nothing to make it stop reading at the end of the buffer you pass it. If you have a 5-byte buffer, and call `gets()` and the user types in 50 characters, then 45 bytes worth of other stack data will be overwritten. This may include the function return address, preserved registers, and all sorts of other valuable stuff, so that your program crashes soon afterwards. `fgets()` is safe because you pass in the size of the buffer as an argument, and it won't put more characters than that into the buffer. No possibility of stack smashing!

Answer (score 1):

In addition to missing `'\n'` in `scanf()` you should allocate more space for `buf`:

[Example](http://ideone.com/o4ZVh)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int m,n; 
    if(scanf("%d%d\n",&m,&n) != 2)
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    char ar[m][n];
    char buf[n+2]; // '\n\0'
    int a,b;
    for(a=0;a<m;a++)
    {
        if (!fgets(buf, n+2, stdin)) exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        for(b=0;b<n;b++) ar[a][b] = buf[b];
    }
    for(a=0;a<m;a++,printf("\n")) for(b=0;b<n;b++) printf("%c",ar[a][b]);
    return 0;
}
```

#### Output

```
abc
def
```